# How to open a folder from an Air 2.0 Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How to open a folder in Windows Explorer or Finder (Mac) from an Air 2.0 Application? I'm using Flex 4 + ActionScript 3.
Seams like I could do it using NativeProcess but I don't want to create a native installer. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found it on [an article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/exploring_file_capabilities.html):

> If you call openWithDefaultApplication on a directory, it will open in your default file explorer application (Finder, Windows Explorer, Nautilus, and so on)

It doesn't worked because my application was targeted for Air 1.5, so I just added the following line in my application.xml and the problem was solved:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0">
```